# Convert flowfile content column from Hexadecimal to decimal using UpdateRecord processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I am getting a flowfile with one of the column in content as hexadecimal value. My requirement is to derive a new column with the corresponding decimal value. If i try to use UpdateRecord Processor with replacement value strategy as "Literal value" and try to update the existing field value by using ${field.value:fromRadix(16)} then it is working fine. But if i try to derive a new column using the value of the existing column then am getting run time error. I used Replacement Value strategy as "Record path value" and dynamic property value as ${/existing_column:fromRadix(16)}. Could you please let me know what am missing here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set the strategy as "Record Path" then the value has to be a valid record path statement after EL evaluation and the statement you have is not valid:  `${/existing_column:fromRadix(16)}`. It will fail because when it goes to do EL first, EL doesn't know when `/existing_column` is.

There really needs to be a record path function for fromRadix so that you could do `fromRadix( /existing_column, 16)`.

Without that I think you need to do a two step process...

Step 1 - First UpdateRecord has `/new_column = /existing_column` to create a new column with hex value of the original column.

Step 2 - Second UpdateRecord has `/new_column = ${field.value:fromRadix(16)}` to convert the new column.

Comment: Yes Bryan. I completed the development with the above suggested approach only. Already am using QueryRecord to do some transformations. I covered the step 1 as part of QueryRecord and implemented Step 2 using UpdateRecord with strategy as "LiteralValue". I don't see fromRadix() function for RecordPath language in the documentation https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/record-path-guide.html#overview

Comment: correct, fromRadix currently does not exist in record path